# A few image maps with JavaScript in a single page

Tags: javascript, html

I’m using [this script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagetooltip.htm) to have an image with some pop-ups when the cursor is on some zones of the image. For exemple, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<link href="/Scripts/ddimgtooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ddimgtooltip.js"></script>

<img class="aligncenter" alt="click map" src="/images/my-image.png" usemap="#mymap" width="300" height="424" border="0" />

<map id="mymap" name="mymap">
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="46,168,63,160,84,270,68,273" href="" target="" rel="imgtip[11]"/>
</map>
```

It works well when I have only one image map per page. But when I but a second one, I don't have any pop-up (only the link). The image map part is working, but not the JavaScript part. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to do with your JavaScript file?

Near the top of `ddimgtooltip.js` is where you define your tooltips:

```
tooltips[0]=["red_balloon.gif", "Here is a red balloon<br /> on a white background", {background:"#FFFFFF", color:"black", border:"5px ridge darkblue"}]
tooltips[1]=["duck2.gif", "Here is a duck on a light blue background.", {background:"#DDECFF", width:"200px"}]
tooltips[2]=["dynamicindex14/winter.jpg"]
tooltips[3]=["dynamicindex17/bridge.gif", "Bridge to somewhere.", {background:"white", font:"bold 12px Arial"}]
```

Each tooltip's syntax should be as follows:

```
tooltip[x]=['path_to_image', 'optional desc', optional_CSS_object]
```

Then, ensure your `rel` paths are accurate. For this example (pulled from your provided link), use this:

```
<p><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com" rel="imgtip[0]">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://javascriptkit.com" rel="imgtip[1]" style="float:right">Link 2</a></p>
<p><a href="http://cssdrive.com" rel="imgtip[2]">Link 3</a></p>
<p><a href="http://codingforums.com" rel="imgtip[3]">Link 4</a></p>
```

Plus, you are using an **ancient** version of [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Try:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: usemap="#mymap" concerns the image map, right ? And the two image maps are working well, so i think this part is okay.

Comment: Do you have an active [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? I don't know if we have enough content to proceed further...